# How to get a the Name of an Object for a UI-List. Func<T, string> GetName, or propertyName and GetPropValue(propertyName)

Tags: c#, function, parameters

I and a schoolmate are working on a project for school and are currently arguing about the right way to tell our UIList class how to get the DisplayedName of one of its items.

His Solution was to pass the name of the corresponding property of one of the items as a parameter in the Constructor of the UIList and then use GetProperty to get the names when needed.

```
Example (Not actual code):

public UIList(..., List<T> elementsToDisplay, string DisplayMemberPath)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elementsToDisplay.FirstOrDefault().GetPropValue(DisplayMemberPath).ToString())
}
```

When i needed to expand the UIList class i thought that it could lead to Problems concerning typos and readability and that we could also change the name to something more speciffic if we needed to debug something (add the id to the name or sth like that), so i replaced the DisplayMemberpath with a GetName Function.

```
Example (Not actual code):
public UIList(..., List<T> elementsToDisplay, Func<T, string> GetElementsName)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetElementsName(elementsToDisplay.FirstOrDefault()));
}
```

His argument is that he doesn't want to write a Lambda expression every time he creates a UIList and that it's easier to just write the name of the property name. (I don't really get what he means because autocompletion is as fast as writing the name)

Is his solution really better, or are both of them really bad practice and should be replaced immediately?

Comment: Create `ISupportsDisplayName` with a read-only `DisplayName` property. Have the class implement the interface. Also read up on `nameof` (although I _think_ that won't help here).

Comment: A generic lambda approach will be at the cost of an allocation, However, its less prone to error and it is a load faster then any reflection approach. Or as has been suggested, an interface, no allocations, yehaa. You and your friends can both concede defeat :)